# finding mysqlpid through c/c++ program

Tags: c++

I need to Write a C/C++ program which finds the MySQL PID file and prints its content assuming that the application will run on the same system running MySQL.
Please share some idea that how should I do it?If possible provide some link from which I can get details.

Comment: @abalogh:it is running on windows7.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your question and thought you were looking for the pid (process identifier) of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FindFirstFile Windows API function to look for the filename. Sample code here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx

Or you could use the --pid-file switch to start MySQL?

Comment: If you don't know what the file is called, `FindFirstFile` won't help you. If you *do* know what it's called, then `FindFirstFile` is unnecessary (because you can simply open the file directly).